# url directly giving xml how to use in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, xml

from currency feed URL I am getting xml data directly 
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22SGDUSD%22,%20%22SGDINR%22,%20%22SGDCNY%22,%20%22SGDEUR%22)&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys

I found code to convert xml2json here 
http://plnkr.co/edit/pob3c28vkC3qR1hXfCv0?p=preview

my code is

```
<a target="_self" href="http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?                         q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22SGDUSD%22,                        %20%22SGDINR%22,%20%22SGDCNY%22,%20%22SGDEUR%22)&env=store://datatables.org/allt        ableswithkeys" download="D:\sample.xml">
```

currencyFeedURL

but my url is giving direct xml dont know how to store it to desired location and give it as sample.xml

Comment: Have deleted my answer, you are right - you are doing the exact same in your plnkr. But I really dont understand your question, and after the comment I am more confused. Hopefully a more bright person can answer :)

Comment: pls dont delete your previous answer. its really helpful.. probably i should ask question in another way.  If you keep the plunker demo it would have been useful for me and others so pls add your previous answer